# Append the count to a variable name in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
count = 0
3.times do |survey|
  count = count + 1
  @psychological_safety_score_ + count.to_s  = Team.get_psychological_safety_score(@team, count)
end
```

This gives me the error `undefined method to_s= for 1:Integer`

I'm also tried `@psychological_safety_score_ + #{count.to_S}` with no luck.

The end goal is to get instance variables of `psychological_safety_score_1...3`

Comment: Matheus' answer is correct. In addition, you can remove the counter by using iterator `.times` method as a counter: `3.times do |count|` it will automatically increase the count value, starting from 0.

Comment: @JCorcuera Wow I just finished adding that exact same comment to my answer. Thanks to you as well, wish I could upvote you.

Comment: Please consider using an `Array` or a `Hash`, instead of multiple ivars. I think you will find these data structures easier to use, both for writes and reads.

Comment: Would a hash like `@psychological_safety_scores[2]` be a better choice? How do you plan to read the variables later in your application when you do not know how many were initialized? Also with a loop and hardcoded counters?

Comment: Ruby has a data structure which is made specifically for storing multiple values. It is called an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). You should definitely look into that.

Comment: Thanks all, yes, I did end up using an array for this, but maybe this will help someone out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby language itself does not allow you to compute variable names by interpolating data into them.

It is still possible to do what you want though, using [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set).

```
score = Team.get_psychological_safety_score(@team, count)
variable = :"@psychological_safety_score_#{count}"
instance_variable_set variable, score
```

Also, `count` is redundant. [`Integer#times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times) iterates `self` times, yielding the current index to the block. It can be used as the count.

Comment: The variable needs to have the `@` in the name, otherwise it throws an error.